# Rails rake mechanize - Error - No such file to load -- Mechanize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mechanize

---

### EDIT: Forgot to include mechanize in the gem file

I get a error that says: `No such file to load -- Mechanize'` when I run: `rake import_stats`.

My `statistik.rake` in lib/tasks

```
desc "Importer statistikker"
task :import_stats => :environment do

require 'Mechanize'
agent = WWW::Mechanize.new

agent.get("http://www.iqmedier.dk")

form = agent.page.forms.first
form.Username = 'username'
form.Password = 'password'
form.submit

agent.page.link_with(:href => "/Publisher/Stats").click
form = agent.page.forms.first
form.submit

    @stats = agent.page.search('//tr')[-2].search('td').map{ |n| n.text }
        Reklamer.create!(:virksomhed => 'Iqmedier', :dato => '(@stats[1])', :unik_klik => '(@stats[2])', :klik => '(@stats[3])', :unik_vis => '(@stats[4])', :vis => ('@stats[5]'), :leads => ('@stats[6]'), :ordre => '(@stats[6])', :cpc => '(@stats[7])', :earn => '(@stats[8])')
    end
```

I am trying to create a row in the table Reklamer with the scraped data.

Best regards,
A rails beginner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task name is `environment`, not `enviroment`. There's a typo.
Change the line 2.

Comment: That is right but now a get a error that says "No such file to load -- Mechanize"

Comment: Make sure you are configuring the Gem dependency in your Rails project.

Comment: How did you solve this? I also get the error you mentioned.  "No such file to load -- Mechanize" –

Answer (score 0):

To invoke a rake task you do:

```
rake namespace:name_of_the_task
```

So in your case considering you dont have any namespace you should run:

```
rake import_stats
```

You might want a namespace, to do this you have to encapsulate the task within a namespace:

```
namespace :mechanize do
  task :import_stats => :environment do
    ....
  end
end
```

and then execute

```
rake mechanize:import_stats
```

Comment: Get a error : Dont now how to build task 'enviroment'

Comment: are you running the rake from the root of the project?
Do you have a correct Rakefile in the root of the project?

Comment: I am running from the root of the project. And i have the rake file statistik.rake in lib/tasks

Comment: Still get the error: No such file to load -- Mechanize